# Respond and send ICMP only to certain user's mac address

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, ping, icmp

I need to block ICMP requests for all user's except the groupt that is supposed to manage the VM. Since we access the VM via VPN we have a different IP every time we send a ping to the VM, can I only to respond to ping that come from our machine's MAC address? or is there any way to block and restric only to us?

Answer (score 0):

Most VPN servers allow static IP assignment to users. Assign static IP address to the system admins. Then allow those IP addresses on the firewall (ICMP echo request and reply). This is much easier and better than MAC address restriction.